# CentOS 7 on VMware workstation 12 not connecting to connected internet?

Tags: centos, networking, internet, vmware-workstation

I've been trying to connect to internet on CentOS 7 installed virtually on VMWare Workstation 12 and I tried all the network adapters Bridged, NAT, Host-Only, Customs in the setting but nothing seems to be working.
My PC is connected to WiFi and have internet access.

After looking for quite a while I got one solution online using `DHClient -v` but that too is not working for me and giving me this error (Down Below).

Please Help I've been trying to find out a solution to this problem for quite long now. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
[osboxes@binovizer ~]$ sudo dhclient -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.5
Copyright 2004-2013 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

No broadcast interfaces found - exiting.
```

Comment: It seems like you do not have any interfaces set up for the guest in your hypervisor. What is the output of `ip l`?

Comment: @Rabban
ip l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

Comment: You need to use your hypervisor (VMWare Workstation 12) to add a network device to the guest - my recommendation would be a bridged or a NAT device. When you boot up the guest check `ip l` again, and that should now show you a new device apart from the loopback.

Comment: How to add a network device?
I have tried using bridged and NAT but it did not worked